# Convert date from 'Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the time from the format "Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" to YYYY-MM-DD.

When I try to alert() the date then this will show the date like the following
- Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

But I need the time in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Are there any built function to convert?

Comment: How are you getting the date?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD in IST? In local time? In UTC?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want the output to be UTC?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can parse the date using the `Date` constructor, then spit out the individual time components:

```js
function convert(str) {
  var date = new Date(str),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
}

console.log(convert("Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))
//-> "2011-06-08"
```

As you can see from the result though, this will parse the date into the local time zone.  If you want to keep the date based on the original time zone, the easiest approach is to split the string and extract the parts you need:

```js
function convert(str) {
  var mnths = {
      Jan: "01",
      Feb: "02",
      Mar: "03",
      Apr: "04",
      May: "05",
      Jun: "06",
      Jul: "07",
      Aug: "08",
      Sep: "09",
      Oct: "10",
      Nov: "11",
      Dec: "12"
    },
    date = str.split(" ");

  return [date[3], mnths[date[1]], date[2]].join("-");
}

console.log(convert("Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))
//-> "2011-06-09"
```

Comment: Hi, how can i convert "Thu Jun 09 2011 10:12:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" to date and time (mm/dd/yyy ss:mm:hh)

Comment: Hey thanks but i am getting "TypeError: str.split is not a function" this error in console and it is not working in my case

Comment: I want this format MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm -> 2018-11-22 19:00 can you help me please

Comment: I am just getting -- in the console window

Comment: hi i want "MMM  D , YYY" (SEP 09,2020) in this form and i am getting MMM-D-YYY (SEP-09-2020) in this form how can i do that and i am using this code                                  function convert(str) {
  
    date = str.split(" ");

          return [ date[1], date[2], date[3] ].join(" ");

}

console.log(convert("Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way for me to convert a date was to stringify it then slice it.

```
var event = new Date("Fri Apr 05 2019 16:59:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)");

let date = JSON.stringify(event)
date = date.slice(1,11)

// console.log(date) = '2019-04-05'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function convert(str) {
    var date = new Date(str),
        mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
        day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        hours  = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
        minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    return [ date.getFullYear(), mnth, day, hours, minutes ].join("-");
}
```

I used this efficiently in angular because i was losing two hours on updating a $scope.STARTevent, and $scope.ENDevent, IN console.log was fine, however saving to mYsql dropped two hours.

```
var whatSTART = $scope.STARTevent;
whatSTART = convert(whatever);
```

THIS WILL ALSO work for END

Answer (score 3):

Above solutions will work only if its a **string**. Input type date, gives you output in javascript **date object** in some cases like if you use angular or so. That's why some people are getting error like "TypeError: str.split is not a function". It's a date object, so you should use functions of Date object in javascript to manipulate it. 
Example here:

```
var date = $scope.dateObj ; 
//dateObj is data bind to the ng-modal of input type dat.
console.log(date.getFullYear()); //this will give you full year eg : 1990
console.log(date.getDate()); //gives you the date from 1 to 31
console.log(date.getMonth() + 1); //getMonth will give month from 0 to 11
```

Check the following link for reference:

Comment: This is the correct way. Ty. If anyone still gets the error, add a 0 to the month. Eg: `('0'+date.getMonth()).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function convertDatePickerTimeToMySQLTime(str) {
        var month, day, year, hours, minutes, seconds;
        var date = new Date(str),
            month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        hours = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
        minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        seconds = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

        var mySQLDate = [date.getFullYear(), month, day].join("-");
        var mySQLTime = [hours, minutes, seconds].join(":");
        return [mySQLDate, mySQLTime].join(" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

var first_date = new Date("Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var start_date = first_date.toLocaleDateString().slice(0,10);

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
const getDate = (str) => {
  if (str !== undefined) {
    var date = new Date(str),
      mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
      day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

And call like this

getDate(input-date);
retult: 2022-03-25

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the symbol between each number follow use this

```js
function dateConverter(str){
   var date = new Date(str),
   mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
   day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
   hours  = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
   minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
   seconds  = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
   year = date.getFullYear();
   return `${year}/${mnth}/${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
}
console.log(dateConverter("Thu Jun 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))
```