# Set datetime format from google visualization to datatables

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, datatables, date-format, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to load my fusion table data using google visualization and show it using datatables 1.10.3 from [this](http://www.datatables.net/download/index) .

In my fusion table date format is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

When i load it using GVIZ my date format still `dd/mm/yyyy`, but when show it using datatables the format change to e.g : `Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time).`

How to change the format like in fusion tables `dd/mm/yyyy`? I also check how to fix it from datatables 
forum but it's still show error or not show to `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Can anybody help me? thanks for any help.

---

I just fixed the code by using this :

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#example').dataTable({
                                    /*
                                        "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],  "columnDefs": [ {
                                        "targets": [ 0, 1 ],
                                        "orderable": false
                                        } ]
                                    */  
                                    "columnDefs": [{
                                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                            //The date value was 2011/04/25, now it's reversed.
                                            //Wed Sep 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
                                            var fullDate = row[4].toString();
                                            date = fullDate.substring(8, 10);
                                            month = fullDate.substring(4, 7);
                                            year =fullDate.substring(11, 15);
                                            fixDate = date.concat(" "+month+" "+year);
                                            return fixDate;
                                        },
                                        "targets": 4,
                                    }]
                                });
                            } );
```

but I have more than 1 columns how to set this code to table id 4,10 and my sortable setting column?

```
"order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],  "columnDefs": [ {
                                        "targets": [ 0, 1 ],
                                        "orderable": false
                                        } ]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
  
  <title>DataTables example - Base style - compact</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/demo.css">
  <style type="text/css" class="init">
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webgis.tanamuntukkehidupan.org/js/geoxml3_kmlStr.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
   
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
   } );
   
  </script>
  
  <script language="javascript">
   var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){   
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   
   function getData(dataSource, divID)
   {  
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject) 
    {   
     var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
     XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource, true);
     XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
     {     
      if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4
      && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
      {
       obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
      } 
     }
     XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
   }
   
  </script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body class="dt-example">
  <div class="container">
   <section>
    <h1>DataTables example <span>Base style - compact</span></h1>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     //script Table  Jenis Pohon
     // Fusion Table data ID
     //https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad
     var FT_TableIDSP = '1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR';
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});
     
     function getTableStatistikPohon() {
      // set the query using the parameters
      var FT_Query_StatistikPohon = "SELECT 'idStatistikPohon', 'Kelompok Penanam',"+
      "'Tanggal Penanaman', 'Blok Wilayah', 'Jenis Pohon', 'Tinggi Pohon', 'Jumlah Pohon',"+
      "'Kondisi Pohon', 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir' FROM "+FT_TableIDSP+" ORDER by 'idStatistikPohon'";
      var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query_StatistikPohon);
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
      
      //set the callback function
      query.send(StatistikPohonTable);
     }
     
     // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      getTableStatistikPohon();
     });
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#refershstatistikpohon").click(function(){
       alert("Table Refresh");
       getTableStatistikPohon();
       google.setOnLoadCallback(getTableStatistikPohon);
      });
     });
     
     function StatistikPohonTable(response) {
      if (!response) {
       alert('no response');
       return;
      }
      if (response.isError()) {
       alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
       return;
      } 
      //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
      //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
      
      numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
      
      if (numRows <= 0) {
       document.getElementById('tableStatistikPohon').innerHTML = "Data Kosong";
       return;
      }
      
      fusiontabledata = "<table id='example' class='display compact' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"
      fusiontabledata += "<thead>"
      fusiontabledata += "<tr>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Edit </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Delete </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> ID </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Kelompok Penanam </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tanggal Penanaman </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Blok Wilayah </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Jenis Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tinggi Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Jumlah Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Kondisi Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Koordinat Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "</tr>"
      fusiontabledata += "</thead>"
      fusiontabledata += "<tfoot>"
      fusiontabledata += "<tr>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Edit </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Delete </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> ID </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Kelompok Penanam </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tanggal Penanaman </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Blok Wilayah </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Jenis Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tinggi Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Jumlah Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Kondisi Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "<th> Koordinat Pohon </th>"
      fusiontabledata += "</tr>"
      fusiontabledata += "</tfoot>"
      fusiontabledata += "<tbody>"
      
      for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
       fusiontabledata += "<tr>";
       fusiontabledata += "<td><a onclick='editStatistikGo("+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0)+")' href='#'><img title='Edit' src='images/edit.gif'></a></div></td>";
       fusiontabledata += "<td><a onclick='deleteStatistik("+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0)+")' href='#'><img title='Delete' src='images/action_delete.gif'></a></div></td>";
       
       for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        if(j < 7){
         fusiontabledata += "<td>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, j)+"</td>";
        }
        else if(j == 7){
         fusiontabledata += "<td>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 7)+"</td>";
         
        } 
        else if (j > 7){
         fusiontabledata += "<td>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, j)+"</td>";
        }
       }
       fusiontabledata += "<td><div align='center'><a href='../preview.php?id="+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0)+"' target='_blank' >Lihat di Peta</a></td>";
       fusiontabledata += "</tr>";
      }
      fusiontabledata += "</tbody>";
      
      fusiontabledata += "</table>";
      fusiontabledata += "<div id=\"txtHintStatistik\"></div>";
      fusiontabledata += "<div id=\"tStatistikRes\"></div>";
      document.getElementById('tableStatistikPohon').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').dataTable();
      } );
      
     }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     getTableStatistikPohon();
    </script>
    <div id="tableStatistikPohon"></div>
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a fiddle based on your `example` table:

```
$(function(){
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
           "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                //The date value was 2011/04/25, now it's reversed.
                return row[4].split("/").reverse().join("/");
            },
            "targets": 4
        }
    ]
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/x31pcgv2/2/

Comment: thanks Robert for your answer. I just update my snippet. My date format was "Wed Sep 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)" how to change the date to dd/mm/yyyy using your split technique. I tried from  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) but the date still not change to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I search from stackoverflow there is the solution from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291225/convert-date-from-thu-jun-09-2011-000000-gmt0530-india-standard-time-to-yyy) but how to implement to my code? when I tried it show error or not change anything