# Converting date from mongoDb/mongoose in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application using mongodb/mongoose with a field called eventStartDate set to a type of Date

```
eventStartDate: {
  type: Date,
},
```

I'm using a date picker input field with type='date'.  When I select a date, and submit it goes into the database as 2022-09-03T00:00:00.000+00:00 butt when I try to query it (I'm using graphql) I just get a long string of numbers like this: 1666396800000.

How can I convert that date to display it properly as 09/03/2022.

Comment: can you please check these once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291225/convert-date-from-thu-jun-09-2011-000000-gmt0530-india-standard-time-to

Comment: I tried that but in the console log (console.log(convert(eventStartDate) I get NAN-NAN-NAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I posted the question after days of trying to figure it out, then figured it out.

When I just tried to convert the data as it was I either got Invalid date or NaN or something like that.  Then I rezlied the ling interger was a string so I tried converting it to an integer and then used momentjs to format the date.

```
let tempDate = parseInt(eventData.eventStartDate);
    setEventStartDate(moment(tempDate).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I set the date ad YYYY-MM-DD so it would populate the date input field when going back to edit the event.